# Extracting JSON from a string response using Apache JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am making an HTTP request using Apache JMeter.

The response has the following format:

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-powered-by: Express
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-methods: HEAD, POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
access-control-allow-headers: origin, content-type, X-Auth-Token, Tenant-ID, Authorization
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
content-length: 24
etag: W/"18-8MkH0L5c1ZW7PPuEY1rZ3jKFme0"
date: Thu, 08 Apr 2021 12:28:37 GMT
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 90
server: envoy

{"id":"548b23a3.4f6a4c"}

I need a way to extract the JSON id value to a variable to make another one request.

JSON extractor needs a pure JSON format as response but in my case i need to skip all these headers from the body response.

Any ideas how could i make it with the Apache JMeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **really** have all this as a part of response body (however it looks like [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) to me) you should always be able to fall back to the [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) which doesn't have any limitations.

Example regular expression:

```
"id"\s*:\s*"(.+?)"}
```

Demo:

[image]

Explanation:

- `\s` - meta character for whitespace
- `*` - any number of whitespaces
- `.` - match any character
- `+` - repetition
- `?` - don't be greedy, stop at first match

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)
- [Perl5 Regex Cheat Sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I had a white space at the end of reg expresission! I undrestood it after using the regex tester!

Answer (score 0):

Another clean way is to use is `JSON Extractor` (Post Processor). This is pretty helpful when you will have complex json (multiple nested objects) returned.

[image: Extracting JSON values]

More details here: https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/03/09/how-to-extract-data-from-json-response-using-jmeter/#jmeter-jsonpath-plugin